# Virtual Box Kali not getting IPv4 address on Nat Network (DHCP server not running)

Tags: networking, virtualbox, windows-11

IPv4 is not getting assigned on Kali virtual box. It is working on `Nat` and `Bridged Adapter` and none of the other Networks are getting connected to the internet or getting an IP address.

Here are the Properties of Kali Linux:

[image: Properties]

[image: Adapter]

---

**Nat Network**:

[image: Network]

Output of `VboxManage list dhcpservers`

[image: Vboxmanage list dhcpserver output]

---

`ifconfig` output (no ip is assigned):

[image: ifconfig output]

it won't connect,it keeps on loading:

[image]

---

**Commands I have tried:**

```
┌──(rootkali)-[/home/kali]
└─# ifdown eth0                                                                                                                                                             1 ⨯
ifdown: unknown interface eth0
                                                                                                                                                               
┌──(rootkali)-[/home/kali]
└─# ifup eth0                                                                                                                                              1 ⨯
ifup: unknown interface eth0
                                                                                                                                                               
┌──(rootkali)-[/home/kali]
└─# ip a show eth0                                                                                                                                         1 ⨯
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 08:00:27:0e:34:8d brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet6 fe80::a00:27ff:fe0e:348d/64 scope link noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
                                                                                                                                                               
┌──(rootkali)-[/home/kali]
└─# ip link set enp0s31f6 down
Cannot find device "enp0s31f6"
                                                                                                                                                               
┌──(rootkali)-[/home/kali]
└─# /etc/init.d/networking restart                                                                                                                         1 ⨯
Restarting networking (via systemctl): networking.service.
                                                                                                                                                               
┌──(rootkali)-[/home/kali]
└─# /etc/init.d/networking stop
Stopping networking (via systemctl): networking.service.
                                                                                                                                                               
┌──(rootkali)-[/home/kali]
└─# /etc/init.d/networking start
Starting networking (via systemctl): networking.service.
                                                                                                                                                               
┌──(rootkali)-[/home/kali]
└─# sudo systemctl restart networking
                                                                                                                                                               
┌──(rootkali)-[/home/kali]
└─# systemctl restart NetworkManager
                                                                                                                                                               
┌──(rootkali)-[/home/kali]
└─# ifconfig                  
eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet6 fe80::a00:27ff:fe0e:348d  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 08:00:27:0e:34:8d  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 13  bytes 4303 (4.2 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 83  bytes 13878 (13.5 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

**Edit:**

Tried with Parrot Os, IP is not getting assigned. Seems like problem with virtual box or windows.

Virtual box version: 7.0.10

**Edit 2:**

I think the dhcpserver is not running, even after running the command
`VBoxManage.exe dhcpserver start --network NatNetwork`

```
C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox>VBoxManage.exe dhcpserver start --network NatNetwork

C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox>VBoxManage.exe dhcpserver restart --network NatNetwork
VBoxManage.exe: error: Failed to restart the server
VBoxManage.exe: error: not running
VBoxManage.exe: error: Details: code E_FAIL (0x80004005), component DHCPServerWrap, interface IDHCPServer, callee IUnknown
```

Comment: In the Kali machine, Settings, Advanced Network Configuration, what adapter do you see?

Comment: @John Ethernet > Wired connection 1

Comment: @RomeoNinov Can you explain on how to do that?

Comment: If your host is connected properly,  Kali should see the host network assuming VBOX is set to NAT or Bridged and NOT Host Only.

Comment: It is set to `Nat Network`.

Comment: @Yashik, my mistake, please ignore

Comment: If VBox is set to NAT and Kali shows Wired Network, the settings are correct. Try spinning up a test Kali machine. It was perhaps not installed correctly (posted from my working Kali VM).

Comment: I have Reinstalled virtual box, tried with latest Kali Linux 2023 and old version 2021. I use the ova file provided by kali.org.

Comment: Download the Kali bare metal ISO and install that in VBOX.  That is how I install Kali and that should work.

Comment: Ok I'll try that

Comment: It takes about 90 minutes to download and set up a VM. Please let us know if you got it working.  @Yashik

Comment: @John I installed Parrot os in virtual box still the problem persists.

Comment: If the problem persists in a different OS VM then there must be something wrong with Virtual Box.

Comment: @John virtual box version 7.0.10